# FunctionExecutor of Tmds.ExecFunction library throwing error

Tags: c#, .net-core, lambda

I am working on a .NET Core application. I have to run some code in a separate process, I am using `Tmds.ExecFunction` library for that.

Here is my code:

```
if (renderType == "pdf" || renderType == "xls")
{
        FunctionExecutor.Run(() =>
        {
             var result = report.Execute(GetRenderType(renderType), 1, parameters);
             buffer = result.MainStream;
        });
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func'

I tried to return an int in lambda function but still getting error. I am stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which method in the code has return type `Func<int>` ?

Comment: I think the lambda method @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: https://github.com/amh1979/AspNetCore.Reporting/issues/9#issuecomment-808823583
This is from where i saw that code @ChetanRanpariya